# C++ cast void* when not sure what the type is

Tags: c++, casting, void-pointers

how can I cast void* to another type in C++, when I'm not sure what the other type is.
this is a sample of my code:

```
class A
{
};
class B
{
};
void main()
{
    void * p;
    if (rand() % 2)
        p = new A();
    else
        p = new B();

    A * a = NULL;
    B * b = NULL;
}
```

I want a code to cast the pointer p to A* if its type is A* and put the answer in a,
else cast the pointer p to B* if its type is B* and put the answer in b.

I tried static_cast and regular cast, but they both cast any way without making runtime check, and even if the cast is not correct, they don't throw an exception.

Comment: @101010 That doesn't help.

Comment: `void *` is usually not the solution for anything in modern C++.

Comment: You quite simply cannot do that purely with `void*`. No dice. Even if it worked, it would be a crutch. Have a look at Boost.Any instead. Also, `void main` is invalid.

Comment: @NeilKirk proper way to cast from `void*` to other type is `static_cast`.

Comment: @101010 Correct, but that's not the problem asked.

Comment: I know that its not the solution, the problem is that I have a code and I need to improve it, making as less changes as possible.

Comment: @KonradRudolph or use polymorphism instead of this mess...Even inheriting from a empty class (with virtual destructor) would allow you to use dynamic cast.

Comment: @SaeedSryheni To best answer your question, we need to know the relationship between A and B. (Are A and B both a C, are A and B completely independent).

Comment: they are completely independent. if they were not, I would use dynamic_cast.

Comment: Then this design makes a false equivelency. If they are not interchangable, they shouldn't be treated as such. Personally, I think that something along the lines of `A* a = NULL; B* b = NULL; void* p = (rand() % 2) ? (a=new A()) : (b = new B());` is the best you'll get while still having a p pointer. Else I'd highly suggest putting in the time to refactor the `void*` away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your classes are *polymorphic* then you can rest on facility provided by `typeid` and `typeinfo`(Although you'd rather use virtual functions most often). Otherwise there's no easy way to do this.

If any way you want to do it then you need to replicate that functionality. For e.g:-

```
template<typename T>
class TypeStoringBase
{
  private:
    enum Type { CLASS_A, CLASS_B, CLASS_C ...};
  protected:
    ~TypeStoringBase();
  public:
    ...
};
```

And then derive every class from this class (using *private inheritance* )for which you want to ensure correctness while casting.

Comment: If we are going to force inheritance, simply having a base class `class Object {public: virtual ~Object(){};}` which all the classes inherit from allows you to use dynamic_cast (Providing you continue to use virtual destructors).

Comment: @IdeaHat What do you mean by "Providing you continue to use virtual destructors"? Having virtual in the base class destructor is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the functions not to use void pointers any more, you can use some kind of "safe void pointer" replacement, along the following lines:

```
struct A{};
struct B{};

struct AnyBase
{
    virtual ~AnyBase() = 0;
};
inline AnyBase::~AnyBase() {}

template<class T>
struct Any : public AnyBase
{
    Any(T *p) : p(p) {}
    T *p;
};

void MaybeA(const AnyBase& p1)
{
    const Any<A> *p2 = dynamic_cast<const Any<A>*>(&p1);
    if (p2)
    {
        A *pa = p2->p;
        cout << "Is an A\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Is not A\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    MaybeA(Any<A>(&a));
    MaybeA(Any<B>(&b));
}
```

Boost may have some perhaps tidier implementation of this.
Although you will need to change all your functions, the change itself should be straightforward, and may even detect bugs you didn't know about!

Note that this solution makes no assumptions about the underlying types. They don't need to have virtual functions or be copyable.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own RTTI. Add a common base class which will require its subclasses to report their types. Then use static_cast to get the actual type.

```
#include <stdlib.h>


enum class Type { A, B };

class Base {
public:
    virtual Type type() const = 0;
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class A : public Base
{
    Type type() const { return Type::A; }
};
class B : public Base
{
    Type type() const { return Type::B; }
};

int main()
{
    void * p;
    if (rand() % 2)
        p = new A();
    else
        p = new B();

    Base *base = static_cast<Base*>( p );

    A * a = NULL;
    B * b = NULL;

    if ( base->type() == Type::A ) {
        a = static_cast<A*>( base );
    } else if ( base->type() == Type::B ) {
        b = static_cast<B*>( base );
    }
}
```

Second option is to keep the type information outside the classes, like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

class A
{
};
class B
{
};
int main()
{
    void * p;
    bool is_a;

    if (rand() % 2) {
        p = new A();
        is_a = true;
    } else {
        p = new B();
        is_a = false;
    }

    A * a = NULL;
    B * b = NULL;

    if ( is_a ) {
        a = static_cast<A*>( p );
    } else {
        b = static_cast<B*>( p );
    }
}
```